# What test recorders are available for mobile app testing?

Tags: automated-testing, mobile

I'm looking for test recorder that help me with mobile app testing (Android, iOS, Windows Phone/Mobile). So far, I have found the following.

- Xamarin Test Recorder, still under development
- Ranorex Studio, does not have a test cloud
- eggPlant Mobile, still evaluating this one but it seems that it has no recorder
- SeeTestAutomation, have to evaluate this, but they have a recorder

What other test recorder are available for mobile app testing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be this : http://testdroid.com/products/testdroid-cloud

Comment: Also this : https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

1. [TestComplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestComplete), a multi-platform tool.
2. [iMacros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMacros), although it may be more slated for web tests.

There is a nice [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools) you may want to investigate as well.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_testing#Some_Mobile_Application_Testing_Tools but I'm looking specifically for mobile app testing tools with support for recording scripts. I think I have enough candidates to evaluate now.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the mobile app testing tools with test recoder facility that you have mentioned above, below mentioned tools also contains recorder facility:

1. MonKey Talk
2. Testdroid
3. Robotium
4. iPhone Tester
5. TestStudio
6. DeviceAnywhere
7. Silk Mobile
8. Sikuli
9. TestCafe
10. iMacros
11. TestComplete

Comment: Does the ordered list imply your recommendation?

Comment: I personally have used four of them **1. Robotium, 2. TestCafe 3. Sikuli 4.iMacros.** and found TestCafe very easy to use. Also found a very good atricle which shows difference between Selenium and TestCafe http://onpathtesting.com/automated-testing-tool-testcafe-or-selenium-webdriver/